# Big-O notation finding c and n0

Tags: big-o

I've just been introduced to Big-O notation and I've been given some questions. However I'm confused as to how to determine the value of `n0`.
I have to show that `3n^3  +20n^2 + 5` is O(n^3). So far I have:

```
3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5 <= cn^3

(3 - c)n^3 + 20n^2 + 5 <= 0

5 <= n^3(c - 3) - 20n^2

5 <= n^2(n(c - 3) - 20)
```

I just don't know what to do from here to find n0 and c. Would someone mind explaining?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5 <= cn^3
=> 20n^2 + 5 <= cn^3 - 3n^3
=> 20n^2 + 5 <= n^3(c - 3)
=> 20n^2/n^3 + 5/n^3 <= n^3(c - 3)/n^3
=> 20/n + 5/n^3 <= c - 3
=> c >= 20/n + 5/n^3 + 3
```

Depending on where you want the greater than condition to begin, you can now choose n0 and find the value.

For example, for n0 = 1:

```
c >= 20/1 + 5/1 + 3 which yields c >= 28
```

It's worth noting that by the definition of Big-O notation, it's not required that the bound actually be this tight. Since this is a simple function, you could just guess-and-check it (for example, pick 100 for c and note that the condition is indeed true asymptotically).

For example:

```
3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5 <= (5 * 10^40) * n^3 for all n >= 1
```

That inequality holding true is enough to prove that f(n) is O(n^3).

---

To offer a better proof, it actually needs to be shown that two constants, `c` and `n0` exist such that `f(n) <= cg(n) for all n > n0`.

Using our c = 28, this is very easy to do:

```
3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5 <= 28n^3
20n^2 + 5 <= 28n^3 - 3n^3
20n^2 + 5 <= 25n^3
20/n + 5/n^3 <= 25

When n = 1: 20 + 5 <= 25 or 25 <= 25
For any n > 1, 20/n + 5/n^3 < 25, thus for all n > 1 this holds true.

Thus 3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5 <= 28n^3 is true for all n >= 1
```

(That's a pretty badly done 'proof' but hopefully the idea shows.)

Comment: Now I'm even more confused, the answers that go with the question say that I should choose n0 = 21 and c = 4 :S

Comment: @DomBrown Hrmmm, perhaps I've misunderstood what n0 is. n0 is the point where `3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5` and `cn^3` intersect, correct? That intersection is a function of `c` (indirectly), so there's not one solution for `n0` and `c`.

Comment: My notes say this: Given functions f(n) and g(n) we say that f(n) is O(g(n)) if there are positive constants c and n0 such that f(n) ≤ cg(n) for n ≥ n0

Comment: @DomBrown Right. Big O only has to meet the condition asymptotically.  That means that f(n) can be > cg(n) for part of the domain.  It's just once a certain point is reached (that point being called `n0` here), f(n) must be >= cg(n). To prove the Big-O relation, all you have to do is prove the existence of `c` and `n0`.  (It's worth noting that in my answer, I did not technically prove their existence. I will edit my answer in a moment.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. There's just one last thing I'd like to clear up. Is it possible for there to be multiple answers to this question? i.e. there could be some other two values for n0 and c?

Comment: @DomBrown There are infinitely many solutions to this problem.

Comment: Thankyou for clearing that up for me :) I was getting all stressed because I didn't get the values on the answer sheet!

Comment: @DomBrown Depending on how the question is worded, it might be that they're looking for a particular pair. As for the definition of O though, there are indeed infinitely many solutions.

Comment: If (c, n0) is an answer then (c, n1) is an answer whenever n1 > n0 so there is always an infinite number of answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you have  `f(n) = (3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5)`  and you want to see if it's `O(g(n))` where `g(n) = n^3`, I believe you can take the limit of `f(n)/g(n)` as n->infinity.

Because the limit is 3, you can see that `3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5` only grows as fast as `n^3`.  When you have a polynomial like `3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5`, you can tell by inspection that the largest order term will always be the value of `O(f(n))`.

It's not a lot of help finding n<sub>0</sub> and C, but it's a relatively easy way to determine what the order of something is.  As the others have said here, you can just pick n<sub>0</sub> and then calculate C.

If you choose n<sub>0</sub> = 1, then you have `3*(1^3) + 20*1^2 + 5 = 28`.  So if `c1^3 <= 28`, c must be 28.  You've shown there there is a c and n0 that meets this condition, so you've proved f(n) is O(n^3)

Answer (score 2):

```
3n^3 + 20n^2 + 5 <= cn^3

5 + 20n^2 <= n^3(c - 3)

5/n^3 + 20/n <= c - 3

For n0 = 20, c >= 5, since 5/n^3 + 20/n < 2
```

Comment: Aw, beat me by 30 seconds :). +1

Comment: I believe it should be c>=2?

Comment: 5 > 2 so it's not any different. Any n0 and any c that holds are totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by n^3
 we get
3+20/n+5/n^3<=C
20/n+5/n^3<=C-3

Take C value as 10
20/n+5/n^3<=7

We need to solve this for different values of n until the condition gets satisfied
C=10 and n0 = 3 will give the solution