# How is f(x) = 4x^2 - 5x + 3 is O(x^2) derived

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Here are the steps that are used to prove the above

```
|f(x)| = |4x^2 – 5x + 3|
<= |4x^2|+ |- 5x| + |3|
<= 4x^2 + 5x + 3, for all x > 0
<= 4x^2 + 5x^2 + 3x^2, for all x > 1
<= 12x^2, for all x > 1
```

Hence we conclude that f(x) is O(x^2)

I [referred this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249151/big-o-notation-finding-c-and-n0) But it does not help

Can someone explain the above proof step by step?

1. Why the absolute value of f(x) is taken ?
2. Why and how were all the term replaced by x^2 term?

Comment: You want to know the math behind, or just you want to know why that kind of function is `O(x^2)`?

Comment: @Hackerman The math part.

Comment: Basically is `the absolute value of x is equal to blablabla`...then the steps and solutions for the functions for x > 0 and x > 1.....and it is `O(x^2)` because for example, for example, consider x as an array....there is a square operation in there, so the cost to return all the solutions is   for every item in the array(aka n for the input size), we have to do n more operations. So n * n == n^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preparations

We start by loosely stating the definition of a function or algorithm `f` being in `O(g(n))`:

> If a function `f` is *in* `O(g(n))`, then `c · g(n)` is an upper
>   bound on `f(n)`, for **some non-negative constant `c`** such that `f(n) ≤ c · g(n)`
>   holds, **for sufficiently large `n`** (i.e. , `n ≥ n0` for some constant
>   `n0`).

Hence, to show that `f ∈ O(g(n))`, we need to find a set of (non-negative) constants `(c, n0)` that fulfils

```
f(n) ≤ c · g(n), for all n ≥ n0,                                (+)
```

We note, however, that this set **is not unique**; the problem of finding the constants `(c, n0)` such that (+) holds is *degenerate*. In fact, if any such pair of constants exists, there will exist an infinite amount of different such pairs.

---

#### Analysis

For common convention, we'll analyse your example using variable name `n` rather than `x`.

```
f(n) = 4n^2 - 5n + 3                                            (++)
```

Now, for your example, we may assume, without loss of generality (since we're studying asymptotic complexity: function/algorithm behavior for "large" `n`) that `n > n0` where `n0 > 0`. This would correspond to the analysis you've shown in your question analyzing absolute values of `x`. Anyway, given this assumption, the following holds:

```
f(n) = 4n^2 - 5n + 3 < 4n^2 + 3, for all n > n0
```

Now *let*, again without loss of generality, `n0` equal `2` (we could choose any value, but lets choose `2` here). For `n0 = 2`, naturally `n^2 > 3` holds for `n > n0`, which means the following holds:

```
f(n) = 4n^2 - 5n + 3 < 4n^2 + 3 < 4n^2 + n^2, for all n > n0 = 2
f(n) < 5n^2, for all n > n0 = 2
```

Now choose `c = 5` and let `g(n) = n^2`:

```
f(n) < c · g(n), for all n > n0,
                 with c = 5, n0 = 2, g(n) = n^2
```

Hence, from `(+)`, we've shown that `f` as defined in `(++)` is in `O(g(n)) = O(n^2)`.